# Why is AsyncTask executed sequentially starting with with Android 3.0?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

From Asynctask javadoc:

*When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.*

Does anyone know what sort of errors they are referring to?

Comment: Mostly your classic thread synchronization errors, as I understand it. It wasn't until Android 3.0 that we got into multi-core CPUs. You can still have thread synchronization errors, even on single-core CPUs, but code that might have "just worked" on a single-core CPU (at least most of the time) might now be more prone to failure when two threads can *really* be executing in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

[Race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Example) where sloppy synchronization can lead to nasty, hard to reproduce bugs and crashes.